# Php - Check if cookie value is equal to

Tags: php, cookies

Anyone know how the get the following code to work?

Thanks!

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['first_name'] == "invisible" )) {
     echo 'YES!';
     }
     else {
      echo 'YES!';
     }
```

Comment: Do you get any error? (Maybe: *Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression*)

Comment: if isset AND equals to, and not if isset equals to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should have gotten the following error message with what you posted for code: (if your system was already set to catch errors). See my footnote.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '==' (T_IS_EQUAL), expecting ',' or ')' in...

Plus, you're using 2x YES!, so one of them has to be "NO!", being the latter.

You need to check if the cookie is set AND equals to.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['first_name']) && $_COOKIE['first_name']== "invisible" ) {
     echo 'YES!';
     }
     else {
      echo 'NO!';
     }
```

Your original code's brackets were malformed and were the cause of the parse error:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['first_name'] == "invisible" ))
                               ^ missing       ^ misplaced
```

Had you placed the bracket in its right spot, and for example:

```
$_COOKIE['first_name'] = "John";

if(isset($_COOKIE['first_name']) == "invisible" ){

 echo 'YES!';
 }
 else {
  echo 'NO!';
 }
```

It would have echo'd "YES" (for being set), since the cookie is indeed set, however it would have been a **false positive** to check if it equaled to "invisible".

- So, you must use two seperate conditions.

---

Footnote:

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I know it. Just Change it like this

```
   if (isset($_COOKIE['first_name'])) {
   if ($_COOKIE['first_name'] == "invisible") {
    echo 'YES!';
   }
   else {
   echo 'YES!';
   }
   }
```

Comment: You should always include an explanation of what you changed and why. You also can have multiple conditions in one `if`.